# Showing copied Hindi text on a website

Tags: html, css

I am facing a strange problem, strange probably because I am doing something like this for the first time.

I am developing a website where some text needs to be in **Hindi language** the website itself is in **English**, only some notifications needs to be in Hindi. The client has provided me **Hindi** text in pdf and docx formats along with the font **Kruti dev 010 Regular**, but when I copy the text from pdf or docx files (which by the way are showing the text proparly) and paste it in my editor **PhpStorm** the text which gets pasted is not in **Hindi** it's in **English**, some random alphabets/words, ofcource I understand since my editor's language is not set to **Kruti dev 010 Regular**, I am not able to paste the proper text there, but then how do I show the **Hindi** text on the website, if I can not copy/paste the text ?

Comment: Assuming you have the correct font loading, are you using the `lang` attribute for this text? `<span lang="hi">Your hindi text here</span>`

Comment: @Paulie_D No, but adding it doesn't solve the problem. The problem is the Hindi text is not getting served as Hindi text, copy past and it's suddenly English.

Comment: This will help you: http://www.devanaagarii.net/

Comment: If you don't have the actual font loading then it seems like that's the issue.

Comment: Try like this:  <html lang="hi">

Comment: May it helps you 1. https://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/584624-using-hindi-language-unicode  2. http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?237241-How-to-include-Hindi-characters-in-webpage